# Apache Velocity Template Language

Tags: velocity, vtl

How can i restrict Velocity Hash Map Object (say $ObjectName) to print fully if it is not preceded by property name.

i do not want $ObjectName to print full object value if it is not appended with variable/property name like $ObjectName.fieldName.

putting $ObjectName include entire detail in template while Velocity process the template

Comment: I understand that by _to print fully_ you mean _to display its content_. That should already be the case. Which version of Velocity are you using? You can also check the class of the map object with `$ObjectName.class.name`

Comment: I am Using Velocity 1.7. If we say ObjectName = ( field1="value1" , field2="value2", field3="value3" .. so on).
then by printing my meaning is..
$ObjectName is printing { field1="value1" , field2="value2", fiedd3="value3" .. } . I don't want this complete value to get printed. Object field value should be printed if mentioned like $ObjectName.field1.. but $ObjectName should not print anything..

Comment: Oh, so you want to *avoid* that. Sorry. So what do you want displayed, then? Something like 'Map@0x4e034534" ? Nothing? By the way, are you sure you can't just remove those references from the input template?

Comment: Hi,
issue got resolved after implementing ReferenceInsertEventHandler Provided by Velocity.
I gave implementation of renderInsert method and restrict all object except String.
this method gets call just before PlaceHolder replace with actual value in Writer Object
For More Info:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/375128/configure-velocity-to-render-an-object-with-something-other-than-tostring